# Adding specific authentication in an ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am struggling to find a certain type of authentication for my asp.net project.

Basically the user navigates to a url, and the browser (rather than the page) prompts for a password. (See screenshot).

[image]

How would I add this into my ASP.NET project?

Comment: Are you running on IIS 6 or IIS 7 ?

Answer (score 2):

Just disable Anonymous Authentication & enable Windows Authentication in IIS for your website.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(WS.10).aspx

It's not a project setting, but you can set who has access to your site in your web.config:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871

Answer (score 0):

That's called Integrated Windows Authentication. You can enable it by going to `Control Panel --> Admin Tools --> IIS Manager --> Select your website --> Go to Security and tick off Integrated Windows Authentication`